# Magento 2 product list widget image on mouse over issues

Tags: magento2

I am using a LUMA based custom theme and I've added some sample product which do not belong to the magento 2 sample data.

I have created a few products and added these images which are 518px X 518px.

After that I have added a Product List widget to the homepage which shows these products.

[image]

My problem is have when I hover on the products the div expands and it's not smooth, it's all very jumpy.

Do these images need to be a specify height and width?

Comment: If you inspect carefully using FireBug/Inspect Element `width="240" height="300"`. So image will be resized automatically as defined. Jumpy meaning coming out of Div & will affect Layout?

Comment: Please try to disable product one by one. May be some of your content issue causing that issue. Check for Short Description & Description